# There is no SMTP option in my bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

I've installed Bugzilla in CentOS 5.5. But when I try to configure the Email I find there is no SMTP option in mail_delivery_method list. There are only Test/Sendmail/None. What can I do if I want use gmail server to send email.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your local postfix/exim to relay everything through gmail with your account details.

Answer (score 1):

This means that Email::Send->new()->all_mailers() is not returning an SMTP option (see Bugzilla's MTA.pm). Perhaps you don't have Net::SMTP installed?

Gerv

Answer (score 0):

Configure Sendmail to use Gmail for SMTP:

http://appgirl.net/blog/2009/configuring-sendmail-to-relay-through-gmail-smtp/
http://www.phinesolutions.com/sendmail-gmail-smtp-relay-howto.html

Comment: I used "my $method = 'SMTP';" instead of "my $method = Bugzilla->params->{'mail_delivery_method'};" in "Bugzilla/Mailer.pm" and it works fine.